# How to calculate average from the user input in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

How to calculate average from the user input in vba? The Last two lines of code attempts to calculate the average of the three inputs from user but fails

```
Sub Storedata()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Dim intnum1 As Integer
    Dim intnum2 As Integer
    Dim intnum3 As Integer
    
    Sheet2.Select
    Let intnum1 = InputBox("Enter the 1st number")
    Let intnum2 = InputBox("Enter the 2nd number")
    Let intnum3 = InputBox("Enter the 3rd number")
    
    If intnum1 > intnum2 And intnum1 > intnum3 Then
    MsgBox intnum1 & " is the Highest "
    ElseIf intnum2 > intnum1 And intnum2 > intnum3 Then
    MsgBox intnum2 & " is the Highest "
    ElseIf intnum3 > intnum1 And intnum3 > intnum2 Then
    MsgBox intnum3 & " is the Highest "
    Else
    MsgBox " one of the value is same "
    End If
    
    If intnum1 < intnum2 And intnum1 < intnum3 Then
    MsgBox intnum1 & " is the Smallest "
    ElseIf intnum2 < intnum1 And intnum2 < intnum3 Then
    MsgBox intnum2 & " is the Smallest "
    ElseIf intnum3 < intnum1 And intnum3 < intnum2 Then
    MsgBox intnum3 & " is the Smallest "
    Else
    MsgBox " one of the value is same "
    End If
    
    ActiveCell.Value = intnum1 + intnum2 + intnum3
    MsgBox intnum1 + intnum2 + intnum3 & " Total "
    
    Range("A2").Value = intnum1 + intnum2 + intnum3 / 3
    MsgBox intnum1 + intnum2 + intnum3 / 3 & " Average "
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Wrong math: Add them first - `(intnum1 + intnum2 + intnum3) / 3`

Comment: And you aren't real clear on what "fails" means... are you getting an error? If so, include that in your question.

Comment: The Average output is wrong in my code

Comment: Then yes, you just needed to add them first, then divide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by replacing lines like:

```
intnum1 + intnum2 + intnum3 /3
```

with:

```
(intnum1 + intnum2 + intnum3) /3
```

*(there may be other errors)*

Answer (score 0):

value = WorksheetFunction.Average([your_arguments_here])

simply pass your arguments to this function. like this:

value = WorksheetFunction.Average(intnum1, intnum2, intnum3)